# USB drive cannot be used as root drive after remounting?

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, external-hdd

I'm attempting to configure a raspberry pi 4 to boot from an external disk. I've configured it to boot from the partition ID I get from `sudo blkid` corresponding to my boot partition, and everything is dandy when I plug it in directly after flashing it with the image. I'm followed the instructions in this thread to great success:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=105868

However, things go off the rails when I attempt to resize the partition from its regular ~4gb size to its full 2TB glory. I boot into the SD card's root filesystem, open up gparted, and resize the root partition to extend to the full disk. Then I go to boot and I'm greeted with a message indicating mounting and resizing the root partition failed and my system is in emergency mode.

What gives? Is there a maximum size to the root partition?

I've verified that the PARTUUID I specified in my /etc/fstab and my commandline flags is correct after the resize, as well as tested using /dev/sda2 as a target rather than the PARTUUID. This didn't resolve the issue.

Instead, I've disable quiet booting and observed a few things. First off, when I first boot into the freshly resized disk, I see the following:

[image]

What I think is happening here is that the fsck is timing out, and when I allow this to run its course I reboot and get something different. I get as far as this screen:

[image]

After which it flashes something that looks like a splash screen for a moment and then hangs. When I -FX by way through the consoles, I find that 1 and 7 are black, and 2 through 6 show blinking cursors.

This does not seem to be related to the size of the partition. I resized the partition from the old size to 1MB larger than the previous size, and it still had the same issue.